# How to write a lexer rule in antlr4 to differentiate 2 strings which has common characters?

Tags: string, antlr4, lexer

I have the requirement to write 2 lexer rules (or 1) to differentiate between valid XML string and a valid general string (which is not a comment or double quoted).Here are my rules.

```
XMLTEXT : ~[<&]+ ;

STRINGTEXT :  ~["\\] ;
```

When I pass a string which is part of the XML body like below
antlr4

It matches both the above rules and I want to match to a single rule. Is there any way I can write the above 2 rules in a better way?

Answer (score 0):

No, that won't work.

Without a real-life example, it's hard to give a more specific answer besides pointing you to lexical modes: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md#lexical-modes

Also have a look at how lexical modes are used in the example XML grammar from ANTLR4's repo: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/xml/XMLLexer.g4